# Lightbox 2 - How to add options if lightbox js loaded as a AMD module

Tags: requirejs, lightbox2

For AMD, lightbox is registered as an anonymous module.
How can I set the lightbox options?

Answer (score 0):

Just call `option` on the module you get when you load Lightbox:

```
require(['lightbox'], function (lightbox) {
    lightbox.option({
        'resizeDuration': 100,
    });
});
```